# how to make 1 million inserts in cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra, bulkinsert, cassandra-3.0

I am parsing thousands of csv files from my application and for each parsed row I am making an insert into Cassandra. It seems that after letting it run it stops at 2048 inserts and throws the BusyConnection error.

Whats the best way for me to make about 1 million inserts?

Should i export the inserts as strings into a file, then run that file directly from CQL to make these massive inserts so I dont actually do it over the network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solve such issues using script(s).

The script go through input data and...

1. At each time it takes a specific amount of data from input.
2. Wait for specific amount of time.
3. Continues in reading and inserting of data.

ad 1. For our configuration and data (max 10 columns with mostly numbers and short texts) we found from 500 to 1000 rows are optimal.

ad 2. We define wait time as n * t. Where *n* is number of rows processed in single run of script. And *t* is time constant in millisecond. Value of *t* strongly depends on your configuration; however, for us *t* = 70 ms is enough to make the process smooth.

Comment: What language did you use to effectively do steps 1, 2, and 3? Also are these inserts done from the client (ie. over the network)?

Comment: Also, what do you do when you want to query (select) thousands of rows at once and send them to the client? The way my design is set up is that I have all data points stored in one table, and for me to query datapoints that share an attribute I would have to create a new table and index them according to that attribute (which means storing duplicate data). Would you recommend instead of duplicating data I just store the names of the indexes from the first big table and then for each of those indexes (possibly thousands) I go to the big table and query them one by one ?

Comment: @stark0323 What language: java. Are these inserts done from from the client: yes, we use distributed microservices architecture and some of our application slave nodes perform large inserts, sent via network to master nodes that communicate directly with cassandra. However, we do not allow client (aplication user connected on frontend) to perform such large operations.

Comment: @stark0323 (Selects) Do not hesitate to duplicate data its normal with Cassandra. When we need to send thousands of rows to user, we use paging. But in the most cases our users work with aggregations/projections of specified part of big data. And in these cases, we should always preprocess data first and store results into new table. If original data can change, then it is required to perform preprocessing regularly, lets say once per day or two depending on the data.

Comment: I see. What are your thoughts on having hundreds of of thousands of tables? Do you have any good resources where I could learn paging in Cassandra?

Comment: @stark0323 Instead of having thousands of tables I recommend create table for each "use case" (partition key) and "pack" precalculated data into different columns as, for instance, json. But if you have so many different keys that you have to create table for each you probably have no other choice than create more tables.

Comment: Waiting isn't very good approach - the wait period may vary depending on the load to servers, and either lead to overloading of Cassandra (if time is too low), or not using it's power (if time is too high).

Comment: @stark0323 Regarding the hundreds of thousands of tables - please don't do it. There is quite big overhead of maintaining internal structures per table, and the rule of thumb is couple of hundreds, with max maybe around 500-700 hundreds of tables per cluster

Answer (score 0):

1 million requests - it's not so big number really, you can load it from `cqlsh` using the `COPY FROM` command. But you can load this data via your Java code as well.

From the error message it looks like that you're using asynchronous API. You can use it for high-performance inserts, but you need to control how many requests are processed at the same time (so-called, in-flight requests).

There are several aspects here:

1. Starting with version 3 of the protocol, you may have up to 32k in-flight requests per connection instead of 1024 that is used by default. You [can configure it when creating Cluster object](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/manual/pooling/#simultaneous-requests-per-connection).
2. You need to control how many requests are in-flight, by wrapping `session.executeAsync` with some counter, for example, like [in this example](https://github.com/alexott/datastax-bootcamp-project/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/bootcamp/SessionLimiter.java) (not the best because it limits on the total requests per session, not on the  connections to individual hosts - this will require much more logic, especially around token-aware requests).